Cannot Activate my Virtual Environment in Anaconda in CMD
I have just created my venv virtual environment in Anaconda, but I cannot activate it using CMD.
I have already added my anaconda path to environment variables. I am able to create my venv using the CMD but cannot activate it in the CMD, while I can activate it on Windows PowerShell. I want to work in CMD, so I need it to be activated in CMD.
I am getting this error when I try to activate:
\python\venv\Library\ssl\cacert.pem was unexpected at this time.
Please help me.
Python version: 3.12.
Note: I am using Windows 11


The issue is in file cacert.pem... its inside Library->ssl folder.... its some kind of encryption file, i dont have any clue about it....

Try running conda activate venv -vvv to get more information.

For me, I fixed it by removing parentheses in the path to my environment.
In your case, it's the Generative AI Course (Udemy) folder. Try removing the parentheses and activate that environment again.
